First Template Message Not Delivered Unless User Sends a Message First
Problem:
I’m using the Meta WhatsApp Business API to send template messages. When I try to send the first message using Postman, I get a 200 OK response, but the message is not delivered to the recipient's phone. However, if the user sends me a message first, the API works as expected, and the message is delivered.
Here is the JSON request I'm using:
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "to": "91790******",
  "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "hello_world",
    "language": {
      "code": "en_US"
    }
  }
}

The response I receive is:
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "input": "91790******",
      "wa_id": "91790******"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE3OTA0NjMwMzM3F***dfdffQkI1QzcwNTd**==",
      "message_status": "accepted"
    }
  ]
}

I’ve confirmed that the template (hello_world) is approved and active.
The API request returns a 200 OK response, but the message is still not delivered to the recipient unless they initiate the conversation by sending a message first.
Question:
Why is the message not being delivered when sending it as the first message? How can I send the first template message without requiring the user to send a message first?
Additional Details:
I’m using the Meta WhatsApp Business API.
The template is approved, and the recipient's phone number is valid.

Basically it is for user's security.
you can not send any message other then template to a user until they send any message to you in 24 hours.
consider it as a 24 hour active timeline (after user initiate chat or reply any thing)

thank you for this information

this is marketing message but it not send why

is this happens to all users ? or this scenario is with one contact number ?
also if he is not receiving any message then you will get reason in webhook which will give you error code along with error message
